# Setting js json file of event model in ruby app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm new at rails and I'm stacked. I've tryed to do User with calendar. Every model worked good when they was separate, now i connect it and stacked. Im using gem devise for user and fullCalendar gem.

Here is my js calendar file

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(

    events: "profile.#{window.user_id}/events.json"
  )
```

View of my user profile with cal

```
    <h1>Your events</h1>

<div id='calendar'></div> </div>
<script>
window.user_id = <%= user_signed_in? && current_user.id %>;
</script>
```

My json file

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :name
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time
  json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
end
```

The problem is in Javascript. Error message is:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/persons/profile.1/events.json?start=2015-04-26&end=2015-06-07&_=1432462639832 404 (Not Found)
```

Can someone told me what am i doing wrong? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Can you put the route which handles this request

Answer (score 1):

I think your URL is wrong. Seems like you using dot instead of slash:

```
profile.1/events.json
```

Try to replace `.` to `/`.

FYI: Try to find correct path to actions is use `rake routes` command.